# Why I can not save Crystal reports file on Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports, rpt

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2017 with the "SAP Crystal Reports" extension, when I try to modify the .rpt file visual studio stop working and it crashes (it usually happen when I change the font style or the font size). Also if the application doesn't crash it doesn't save my changes anyway indeed when I reopen the VS project I see the previous version of the .rpt file.

Answer (score 1):

Try cutting (Ctrl+X) the objects that you made changes on and then paste them back in.

Worked for me.